# What is a Weil-Deligne representation?

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, galois-theory

Can anyone explain (or give reference) Weil-Deligne representations, and how they are linked with Galois representations of p-adic field (on l-adic vector spaces or else) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The canonical reference is Tate's "Number Theoretic Background" in the Corvallis volume. He discusses the Weil-Deligne group in Section 4. Here is a brief description:

Fix a local field $K$ with perfect residue field of characteristic $p\neq\ell$, and let $W_K$ be the Weil group of $K$ (this is $\phi^{-1}(\mathbb{Z})$ where $\phi:G_K\rightarrow\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ is the unramified quotient). A Weil-Deligne representation is a pair

$(V,N)$

where $V$ is a char. $0$ representation of $W_K$ on a discrete vector space and $N:V\rightarrow V(-1)$ is a morphism of representations. One important fact is that the category of $\ell$-adic representations of $G_K$ embeds fully faithfully into the category of Weil-Deligne representations.

Anyway, to get the full story, you should probably read [Tate's article](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~csorense/teaching/math205/Tate_Weil.pdf).

EDIT: Another nice reference is Chapter 1 of (the current draft of) [a book by Fontaine and Ouyang](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~yiouyang/galoisrep.pdf).

Comment: Dear Kevin, Note that if $\ell \neq p$, then *every* $\ell$-adic representation of $G_K$ is "potentially semi-stable", and so corresponds to a Weil--Deligne representation.  Regards,

Comment: Dear Matt, Thank you for your comment. I started out trying to write about an arbitrary complete DVF but changed my mind and ended up with some garbage. I have edited to reflect your remark.